# getopt() doesn't return the next argument

Tags: c, getopt

Take a look at this code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char ch;
    int value;
    while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n: o"))!=EOF){
        switch(ch){
            case 'n':
                value = atoi(optarg);
                fprintf(stdout,"\nParameter n");
                //Do something
                break;
            case 'o':
                fprintf(stdout,"\nParameter 0");
                //Do something
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stdout,"\nInvalid!");
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
    }
}
```

When I pass following arguments

```
./program -n 123 -o
```

I get this result

```
Parameter n
```

while I expect to get this

```
Parameter n
Parameter o
```

why isn't getopt() returning next argument in 2nd iteration of the loop?

**Update**

So the code should be like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char ch;
    int value;
    while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n:o"))!=-1){
        switch(ch){
            case 'n':
                value = atoi(optarg);
                fprintf(stdout,"Parameter n (%d)\n", value);
                //Do something
                break;
            case 'o':
                fprintf(stdout,"Parameter o\n");
                //Do something
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stdout,"Invalid!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main problem

Inside the loop, you have:

```
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
```

That's a disaster — don't do it.  You might use those statements after the loop is complete (once), but not in the body of the loop.  It forces the code to skip options; in severe cases, it can end up trying to parse a null pointer or the environment, neither of which is likely to help (and both are undefined behaviour, so YMMV).

#### Tangential issues

Note that you've specified that a blank is one of the options.  Thus someone could write:

```
./a.out -' ' -n 123 -o
```

and the blank would be treated as a flag option (like `-o`).  It probably isn't what you had in mind.  Use `"n:o"` without a space in it.

You print:

```
fprintf(stdout,"\nParameter 0");
```

Three minor issues with that statement:

1. The `0` should be `o` — they're different.
2. Put newlines at the end of output formats rather than at the beginning (unless you want double-spacing).  Note that output may not be generated until a newline is printed, so the newline at the end ensures that printed data appears more timely.
3. It is aconventional to use `fprintf(stdout, …)` rather than `printf(…)`.  Not precisely wrong, but unusual.

The [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function is defined by POSIX to return `-1` and not `EOF` when it finishes the option processing.  This is so that its declaration in `<unistd.h>` isn't tied to the definition of `EOF` from `<stdio.h>`. (The Rationale section says explicitly: *The `getopt()` function shall return `-1`, rather than `EOF`, so that `<stdio.h>` is not required.*)  Some systems, historically, declared `getopt()` in `<stdio.h>`, but POSIX places it in `<unistd.h>` and says that it returns `-1`.

You should include a `break;` after the `default:` case in the switch.  It's a basic defensive programming measure — it ensures no fall-through even if someone adds another case label after the `default:` label.

Comment: wow never realized it had so many mistakes. Thank you so much